# Laravel - Simultaneous AJAX updates causes race condition on model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For my following examples, I'll give mock code since I don't want to show too much unnecessary detail.

So I have a database table like so:

```php
Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->json('settings');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Since `settings` is a JSON, I wanted to have a way to update it partially with my REST controller, like so `/api/settings/setting_group.sub_setting?v=new value`

The above would mutate as something like this: `$setting->settings["sub_setting"] = $new_value;`

I use this to store my translations, so I'll send these simultaneously when the browser client has changed something. `en.links` is just a path in the `settings` JSON.

- `/api/settings/en.links`
- `/api/settings/zh-HK.links`

This problem did not occur when the `v` is a simple string, I assume it is because Laravel works quicker if `v` is not a large PHP array, so a quick timing mitigated the problem. But the race condition did happen when `v` was large.

This is the form data I had when it happened. This is without URL encoding for ease of reading.

```
/api/settings/en.links?
v[0][text]=en link a&
v[0][url]=http://link.a&
v[1][text]=en link b&
v[1][url]=http://link.b&
api_token=xxx

/api/settings/zh-HK.links?
same thing but in zh-HK translation
```

This is the way I treat the input in my controller:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $setting)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $sectioned_setting = Setting::findOrFail($user->section_id);

    // ...validator logic...

    $form_v = $request->input("v")?:"";

    // This line duplicates $setting->settings then make the changes in that clone
    // and set the clone back into the Setting model
    $v = $sectioned_setting->setValue($setting, $form_v);

    $sectioned_setting->save();

    return response()->json([
        "v" => $sectioned_setting->settings  // This line used to just return $v
    ], Response::HTTP_ACCEPTED);
}
```

Here is basically what I received in the Chrome Network tab, if I updated both link text in en and zh-HK at the same time:

```
/api/settings/en.links

{
    en: {
        links: [
            {
                text: "xxxUPDATED",
                url: "xxx"
            },
        ]
    },
    zh-HK: {
        links: [
            {
                text: "xxx",
                url: "xxx"
            },
        ]
    }
}


/api/settings/zh-HK.links

{
    en: {
        links: [
            {
                text: "xxx",
                url: "xxx"
            },
        ]
    },
    zh-HK: {
        links: [
            {
                text: "xxxUPDATED",
                url: "xxx"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, the the zh-HK mutation to the model's field has overwritten that of en. So this should be a race problem. I need the entire updating and saving process be an atomic operation.

Is there anyway to mitigate this problem? How can one safe guard the server?

---

#### EDIT:

After reading, I tried pessimistic locking for selecting and updating, but it also didn't work. (It did for a fraction of my tests. So I consider it not working, or it worked for the few by chance. Though I don't know why the few times it worked.)

I replaced:

```php
$sectioned_setting = Setting::findOrFail($user->section_id);
```

to

```php
$sectioned_setting = Setting::whereId($user->section_id)->limit(1)->lockForUpdate()->first();
```

I'm thinking perhaps because the requests uses different connections to the database, so the locks did not persist.

I guess a possible option is to add a `version` column to the table and manually attempt an atomic operation against that. (So it checks right before it saves, if the refreshed model is having the same version, retry operation if different.) But **I would like to know if there is a way in Laravel to do so.**

Comment: Have you tried queuing the updating events? probably it should help overcome such a problem..

Comment: @mustafa96m How would one do that?

Comment: Hope this helps, https://medium.com/@sirajul.anik/laravel-event-queue-5160b6007eda

Comment: @mustafa96m I don't think they help. I checked a bit, and there isn't a synchronous queue concept in Laravel.

Comment: Then I believe the last available option is this.
 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions

along with lockForUpdate although I'm not sure if it will lead to a deadlock..